# getline not working on second call

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

The second while doesn't work. I tried filestr.clear()/flush() and others with no result. If I comment the first while everything is OK, but I need the number of objects. Somebody help, please

```
   while (std::getline(filestr, line)) {
            if (line.find("<rect") != std::string::npos) count_rect++;
        }
        rect = new Rectangle[count_rect];
   while (std::getline(filestr, line1)) {
        //code
    }
```

Comment: Code is formatted incorrectly. You seem to think that 2nd while loop is *nested*, but actually it is run *after* first loop.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop extracts lines from `filestr` until there's nothing left to read.

It's hard to concieve why you think a second loop will then find more lines. If the second loop had any input to read, the first loop would already have read it.

I cannot confidently suggest a fix because you did not tell us what your code is supposed to do instead. However, assuming `filestr` is a file stream, you may wish to move the *read cursor* to the beginning after your `clear` operation:

```
filestr.clear();               // clear any state flags
filestr.seekg(0, ios::beg);    // move cursor to start so we read everything again
```

If `filestr` is poorly named and actually represents a non-file stream, you can't do this and will need a fresh approach to your pre-scanning algorithm.

Also, you should avoid `new` in favour of `std::vector`. And you should indent your code properly instead of making a mess.